# arrow function syntax {()} and ({})

Tags: javascript, syntax, redux

I was wondering whats the difference of having:

`export const mapStateToProps = ({some}) => ({})`

and

`export const mapStateToProps = ({some}) => {()}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`({some}) => ({})` defines a "concise" arrow function (one with an *expression body*) returning an object that's defined by the object initializer.

`({some}) => {()}` defines a "verbose" arrow function (one with an explicit function body, e.g. `{...}`) containing just `()` and not returning anything. (That particular one is invalid, the `()` must have something inside them. It's also slightly odd — though syntactically valid — to have a freestanding `(...)` expression as a statement.)

---

The `({some})` parameter list which is the same between the two is a *destructuring* parameter list: The function expects an object and retrieves the `some` property from that object.